# How can I utilize SIMD in Zig explicitly?

Tags: simd, zig

After reading the [Zig language reference](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/), I found that the [vector section](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#Vectors) states that a `@Vector` will use SIMD instructions if possible. There is an example following up as

```
const a = @Vector(4, i32){ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
const b = @Vector(4, i32){ 5, 6, 7, 8 };

// Math operations take place element-wise.
const c = a + b;
```

, but I am looking for whether I can write a `for` loop to manipulate a **single** `@Vector` **in place** and **guarantee** to use of SIMD instructions. For instance, I can utilize SIMD instructions as follows in Julia.

```
arr = Vector{Float64}(under, 32)
@simd for i in eachindex(arr)
    @inbounds arr[i] = 2 * i
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: One question per question please - your two questions above are seemingly unrelated and should therefore be in two separate questions on SO.

Comment: Please check the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I have edited my post with a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

There is unfortunately no Zig equivalent to the Julia code you provided.

I don't think there is need for such tags in Zig. It's reasonable to trust the compiler that it will do the right thing: https://godbolt.org/z/KoGbqEvYf. And if it doesn't, you should file a bug on the zig/llvm compiler :D

Somewhat related: [7702](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/7702) [9389](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/9389)